# How to delete everything before a certain character in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a text such as

```
/path/delivery3/afA.csv:afA;0.000;12.015;Spreker-A;;<lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko. <lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko, gaan ons verder praat oor die #um leerbesigheid? [no-speech]
```

using

```
:%s/.*;//
```

gives me

```
English> Niko, gaan ons verder praat oor die #um leerbesigheid? [no-speech]
```

How do I find the first `:` and output

```
afA;0.000;12.015;Spreker-A;;<lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko. <lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko, gaan ons verder praat oor die #um leerbesigheid? [no-speech]
```

Comment: does this work? `%s/[^:]*://`

Comment: Does `dt:` do what you want?

Comment: Or something like this, `s/^.\{-}://`

Comment: @Christian Gibbons Non-greedy should work for your approach, `s/[^:]\{-}://`

Comment: @Rob -- Based on the example, you mean `df:` I think?  (I guess the question's title is a bit misleading.)

Comment: @m_mlvx No. He said everything before the colon.

Comment: @Rob -- The title says "everything before a certain character", but the example says "How do I find the first [colon] and output [the text after the first colon, which does not include that colon]".  It's messy and ambiguous, and if I were more confident of doing the Right Thing, I would edit the title or the question.

Answer (score 1):

See "[How to make regex matchers non-greedy?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-to-make-regex-matchers-non-greedy)"

The Vim non-greedy version of `*` is `\{-}`

So instead of `:%s/.*://`, you should get the result you want with `:%s/.\{-}://`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply this change on a single line:

```
df:
```

If you want to apply it on all lines in a buffer you can record a simple macro using the above normal mode commands or:

```
:%norm! df:
```

If you really want to do it using the `:s` command:

```
:%s/[^:]*://
```